# How to read Nifti(.nii) files stored in HDFS with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, nifti

I'm trying to make a model to train with images of nii format.I could read files from local filesystem with nibabel library **But I dont find any proper library to read nii files from hdfs using pyspark.** I also tried to read using spark binary. None of the techniques did well.

I could read files from local filesystem with nibabel library But i dont find any proper library to read nii files from hdfs using pyspark. I also tried to read using spark binary.I also tried copying to object and reading as an object.

Here is the code how I read JPG Images for training. Similary I need to read nii files.

```
from sparkdl import readImages
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
img_dir = "MRI_dataset"

AD_df = readImages(img_dir + "/ADTest").withColumn("label", lit(1))
HO_df = readImages(img_dir + "/HOTest").withColumn("label", lit(0))
MCI_df = readImages(img_dir + "/MCITest").withColumn("label", lit(2))



train_df,test_df = (AD_df.unionAll(HO_df)).unionAll(MCI_df).randomSplit([0.6, 0.4], seed = 42)

train_df = train_df.repartition(100)
test_df = test_df.repartition(100)
```

Comment: You'll most likely need to read the binary files using spark then use wrap the binary data using BytesIO and pass that to nibabel. You can do the latter part by using `map` on your RDD or Dataframe. If you include the code you have so far, even if it throws errors, you're likely to get better answers (but make sure you clean up the code and remove anything not related to the question before posting it).

Comment: See how i read JPG Files for training.

Comment: Yep, and [spark has even added an image data source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2018/03/05/image-data-support-in-apache-spark/), yay! Unfortunately the nifti format is just too obscure for direct support so you'll need to do some more work. Take a look at how sparkdl implements readImages, you can follow that pattern.

Comment: Is there any way to read files via http streams. There are ways to stream it with Rest API

Comment: You could copy the stream into a ByteIO buffer and pass that to nibabel to read. You'd want to do that as a udf so you could apply it to each image.